# Layout node in parent, but ignore it when computing width

Tags: javafx, layout

So I have a problem where there is a node on top of which I want to render a heads-up display (HUD).

Naturally my approach was to create `StackPane` and place hud on top of said node and make it mouse transparent.

Now - HUD also needs some layout (to place different elements on different corners for example).

Let's now say that there is a `Label` in hud which displays some string which length should always fit in `Label` (so string is fully displayed). By this logic to lay out such changing-length Label on top-right of HUD, we need said hud to have layout pass (so it places label in corner).

But, since HUD needs to be managed for that to happen, there might be a case where text Label's width is larger than underlying (behind hud) Node, which then would cause whole thing (`StackPane`) to adjust to HUD instead of actual content. HUD is supposed to be layed-out, but only if possible, not forced to do so.

I hope I explained it enough - is there some solution to such layout or do I have to make my own and how (hints)?

Comment: What is a "HUD"?

Comment: HUD = [Heads Up Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-up_display)

Comment: Depending on what's underneath (or, specifically, how its width is managed), it might work to use e.g. an `AnchorPane` for the heads-up display and bind its `maxWidth` to the `width` of the component underneath. (I generally don't like using bindings for managing layout, but this might provide a reasonable solution here.)

Comment: A more sophisticated approach would be to write a `Pane` subclass, with a property to hold the underlying content (which should be a `Node`). Override the `computeXXXWidth(double)` and `computeXXXHeight(double)` methods simply to delegate to the content's corresponding `xxxWidth(double)` and `xxxHeight(double)` methods. Then override `layoutChildren()`: all you need to do here is to get the width and height, call `content.resizeRelocate(0, 0, width, height)` (content will fill the container) and then call `resizeRelocate(...)` on each of the HUD-specific components, locating them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @James_D comment. Using StackPane as base because I'm lazy :P

```
public class HUDPane extends StackPane
{
private final Node content;
private final Node hud;

public HUDPane(Node content, Node hud)
{
    this.content = content;
    this.hud = hud;
    this.getChildren().addAll(this.content, this.hud);
}

@Override
protected void layoutChildren()
{
    super.layoutChildren();

    this.hud.resizeRelocate(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}

@Override
protected double computePrefWidth(double height)
{
    return this.content.prefWidth(height);
}

@Override
protected double computePrefHeight(double width)
{
    return this.content.prefHeight(width);
}

@Override
protected double computeMinWidth(double height)
{
    return this.content.minWidth(height);
}

@Override
protected double computeMinHeight(double width)
{
    return this.content.minHeight(width);
}

@Override
protected double computeMaxWidth(double height)
{
    return this.content.maxWidth(height);
}

@Override
protected double computeMaxHeight(double width)
{
    return this.content.maxHeight(width);
}
}
```